# C++ - Simple ifstream error

Tags: c++, ifstream

Could anyone help me figure out who the lime with **ifstream myfile(fileName);** is generating an error upon compilation with g++?

```
string fileName;

cout << "\nPlease enter the name of your input file:" << endl;
cout << "->";
getline (cin, fileName);

cout << "fileName: " << fileName << endl;

string line;
ifstream myfile(fileName);
if (myfile.is_open()){
    while(getline(myfile, line)){
        cout << line << endl;
    }
myfile.close();
} else {
    cout << "Unable to open file"; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have C++11 support, you need to pass a `const char*` to the constructor. You can achieve it like this:

```
std::ifstream myfile(fileName.c_str());
```

See this [documentation for the relevant constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream).

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to a c-string first.

Try myfile((filename).c_str())

Comment: No need for the extra parentheses.